# focus on user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to focus on a user control but it is giving me errors

```
function getFocus() {
    document.getElementById('<%myUserControl.ClientID%>').focus()
}
<a href....  onclick="getFocus()>Click</a>
```

How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
document.getElementById('<%myUserControl.ClientID%>').focus()
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= myUserControl.ClientID%>').focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

<%=myUserControl.ClientID%> missing "="

Comment: I did this but I am getting Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'myUserControl' does not exist in the current context Source Error: Line 5: function getFocus() { Line 6: Line 7: document.getElementById('<%=myUserControl.ClientID%>').focus() Line 8: } Line 9:

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of that which component you want to focus on. If you want to focus on the "Rates". Based on the code you posted on the other question, I suggest you change your code to .

```
<a id="p2" href="#" runat="server">Rates</a>
```

: remove the lable  and then add href to do what you want to do here. 
and then in your javascript: 
`document.getElementById("<%=p2.ClientID%>").focus();`

then you can get Rates focus.